# Cannot create new column with count and retain the GroupBy columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing the following:

```
data_weeks = pd.read_csv('Desktop/Weeks_ids.csv', keep_default_na=True)
data_surveys = pd.read_csv('Desktop/surveys_data.csv', keep_default_na=True)

data_surveys_with_weeks = data_weeks.merge(data_surveys , on=['Date'], how='inner')

data_surveys_with_weeks = data_surveys_with_weeks.groupby(['Store_id', 'Week_id'], as_index=False).transform('count')

data_surveys_with_weeks .to_csv('Desktop/Performance Engine/surveys_count.csv', index=False)
```

However instead of getting a new column with the `count` for `Store_id` and `Week_id` then I am not actually getting this column and I am also missing the `Store_id` and `Week_id` columns.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

just assign the returned series to a new column:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-01-10'),
                   'Week':pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-01-10').week,
                   'store_id': [1,1,1,2,2]*2})

df['group_count'] = df.groupby(['store_id', 'Week']).transform('count')

        Date  Week  store_id  group_count
0 2019-01-01     1         1            4
1 2019-01-02     1         1            4
2 2019-01-03     1         1            4
3 2019-01-04     1         2            2
4 2019-01-05     1         2            2
5 2019-01-06     1         1            4
6 2019-01-07     2         1            2
7 2019-01-08     2         1            2
8 2019-01-09     2         2            2
9 2019-01-10     2         2            2
```

or if you dont want to return everything use `agg`:

```
df.groupby(['store_id', 'Week']).agg('count')

               Date
store_id Week      
1        1        4
         2        2
2        1        2
         2        2
```

## update

you are getting the error because of the additional columns...it will return a frame and not a series so just specify the column to count. See new example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-01-10'),
                   'Week':pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-01-10').week,
                   'store_id': [1,1,1,2,2]*2,
                  'another_col':np.random.randn(10)})

df['group_count'] = df.groupby(['store_id', 'Week'])['Date'].transform('count')
```

or the other example using `agg`:

```
df.groupby(['store_id', 'Week']).agg({'Date':'count'})
```

Comment: `KeyError: 'group_count'` for the first one

Comment: @PoeteMaudit you get the key error on your actual data or the test I created?

Comment: on my actual but my actual are more or less like your example with some additional columns

Comment: @PoeteMaudit use the second option of `agg`: `df.groupby(['store_id', 'Week'], as_index=False).agg({'Date':'count'})`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187596/discussion-between-chris-and-poete-maudit).

Comment: Even the updated is not working as it should. Also I do not understand why I have to specify the `Date` since I am already doing `groupby(['store_id', 'Week'])`. It is a line count based on `['store_id', 'Week']`; the `Date` has no role in it essentially.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit if you just do `df.groupby(['store_id', 'Week'], as_index=False).count()` then it will return a dataframe with a count in all the columns except what you specify in `groupby`. The example should work. I would need to see the actual dataframe in order to help more.[agg doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)